# Event study for multiple firms and multiple dates with for loop

Tags: r, for-loop

I'm doing an event study with the `evReturn` function from the `erer` package.
The purpose is to get abnormal returns for each firm and average abnormal returns over all firms. I can't get the average returns because the function does a seperate execution for each firm but doesn't do one for all firms at once although this is possible with a for loop. I can't seem to get the right loop.

I've tried this method:

1.

```
install.packages("erer")
library(erer)
i <- 1
hh2 <- list()
for(i in 1:3){
  firms <- names(dataset4)[i+1]
  dates <- eventdates2[i]
  print(firms)
  print(dates)
  print(i)
  hh2[[i]] <- 
    evReturn(y=dataset4, firm = firms, event.date=dates, y.date="Timestamp",
             index="NASDAQ", event.win = 3, est.win= 250, digits=4)
}
```

Example from package erer, daEsa is a dataset included in the package.

```
# event analysis for one firm and one event window
hhreturn <- evReturn(y = daEsa, firm = "wpp", y.date = "date", 
index = "sp500", est.win = 250, digits = 3, event.date = 19990505, 
event.win = 5) 

# event analysis for many firms and one event window
hh2return2 <- update(hhreturn, firm = c("tin", "wy", "pcl", "pch"))

# event analysis for many firms and many event windows: need a for loop
```

This last comment is what I need.

Comment: Thank you for the advice! I've added the data.

Comment: I've included the example from the package with the code for a better understanding, the dataset daEsa is included in the package. My code works for a separate analysis of each firm (N=1) but not across firms. The output should be like hhreturn2 in the example, where an analysis is made for all 4 firms (can be seen in the output, N should be number of firms).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Multiple dates:

```
hh2 <- list()
for(i in c(daEsa$date[3000], daEsa$date[3001])){
  firms <- colnames(daEsa)[12:ncol(daEsa)]
  print(firms)
  print(i)
  hh2[[i]] <- 
    evReturn(y=daEsa, firm = firms, event.date=i, y.date="date",
             index="sp500", event.win = 2, est.win= 250, digits=4)
}
```

Multiple *event windows* (not *dates*):

```
hh2 <- list()
for(i in c(2, 3)){
  firms <- colnames(daEsa)[12:ncol(daEsa)]
  print(firms)
  print(i)
  hh2[[i]] <- 
    evReturn(y=daEsa, firm = firms, event.date=daEsa$date[3000], y.date="date",
             index="sp500", event.win = i, est.win= 250, digits=4)
}
```

> ```
> [1] "pch" "pcl" "pop" "tin" "wpp" "wy" 
> [1] 2
> [1] "pch" "pcl" "pop" "tin" "wpp" "wy" 
> [1] 3
> ```

Comment: @lode OK fortunately it's pretty much the same. I just tested it and updated my answer. Please let me know if you have further questions and if not please mark this as the solution with the green checkmark :)