# Event study with multiple event dates and multiple companies in R

Tags: r, loops, events, finance

I am trying to run an financial event study, and after reading several posts and packages I still don't know how to handle my problem.

I have three dataframes:

1. Multiple Event dates for multiple firms (sometimes one firm has also multiple event dates)
2. Daily stock prices for those firms
3. Market prices

The df's look like this (excerpt)

```
df1 <- data.frame(date = c("2021-10-25", "2017-09-08", "2018-07-03", "2016-05-23"),
                 key = c("1", "1", "2", "3"),
                 country = c("ITA", "ITA", "LTU", "NLD" ))
df1$date <- as.Date(df1$date)

df2 <- data.frame(date = c("2021-10-24","2021-10-25","2021-10-26","2017-09-08","2017-09-09", "2017-09-10", "2018-07-01", "2018-07-02", "2018-07-03", "2016-05-23"),
                key = c("1","1","1","1","1","1", "2", "2", "2", "3"),
                price = as.numeric(c("40.86", "41.22", "44.41", "35.36", "36.84", "36.71", "20.05", "14.87", "16.80", "12.83")),
                country = c("ITA", "ITA", "ITA", "ITA", "ITA", "ITA", "LTU", "LTU", "LTU", "NLD")
                  )
df2$date <- as.Date(df2$date)

df3 <- data.frame(date = c("2021-10-24","2021-10-25","2021-10-26","2021-10-26"))
df3$ITA <- as.numeric(c("1202.31","1208.73", "1221.14", "1218.46"))                 
df3$LTU <- as.numeric(c("187.43","188.01", "186.98", "187.41"))
df3$NLD <- as.numeric(c("1884.43","1880.00", "1860.98", "1876.74"))
```

I want to find a way on calculating the returns for company i (id is the key) using the stock data for the individual company as well as the market index for the company (the country) using the market model.

The event date should be the date t0 and the event window is around that event date (t-10, t15), and the estimation should be calculated prior to the event window (t-210,t-10).

Since I have a lot of observations, I could not find a proper way to use the estudy2 package in such way that i am able to write a code that conducts the event study without additional "calculation by hand in R".

The other way I tried to solve this problem is to construct a dummy variable "t", which is set to 0 for each event date per company and where I then calculate the dummy from -250 to 15. However this is not solving my issue since I have multiple event dates per companies and I then dont know how to incorporate the market returns.

I also saw this post here: [Event study for multiple firms and multiple dates with for loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51363429/event-study-for-multiple-firms-and-multiple-dates-with-for-loop) using the erer package, however in my case I have multiple indices and not a single one.

Any help would be appreciated.

If my question should not be clear please let me now and i try to update it as good as i know.

Answer (score 0):

You may use the [EventStudy](https://cran.r-project.org/package=EventStudy) package (I am the package author) for solving such extensive financial event studies. All you need is to define the request file (with your firm events and event window parameters) and provide the data. All other stuff is handled by the package. A tutorial on the input files can be found in one of the vignettes [Get Started](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/EventStudy/vignettes/get_started.html).